# Active Directory Problem

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2

I have one server 2008 installed with AD, SQL and IIS. Now I am trying to attach different HDD on this server only. I am able to install windows server 2008 r2 64bit on the server, but when I try to install the ActiveDirectory on the server the setup doesn't get completed and keep processing at following level.

"Configuring Active directory and local host domains ......."

If I attach same HDD on any other PC Active directory setups completes successfully. My server is Xeon quad core with 8GB of RAM.

Can any one help the appropriate solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be some hardware related issue. Please check if you're server is custom build or a branded server. For example while installing AD it checks for your LAN connection and DNS settings, if there is some issue with the LAN card or LAN drivers then it will create an issue while installing AD.

Comment: I will take a try it and will let you know.